# reverse kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know in which way I could do the next things with ros :

I have generated an xyz robot trajectory dependant on a time chart I would like  the robot will do. (for each ms an xyz point is provided)
1/ how to make reverse kinematic and know the position of each axis of the robot ?
2/ I want being able to simulate it. how ?

Regarding 1/ : in real world there are some parameters like inertie, speeds .... can I be sure the simulated computed axis positions will be the same at the same time in real world ?

Regards
Steph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285296/reverse-kinetic/) by [sancelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34102/sancelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials

This shows how to describe your robot so that it may be simulated in Gazebo and operate better with ROS

---

Originally posted by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) with karma: 299 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0